# React - onClick 'expected function, recieved object'

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and wanted to use setState without putting it inside function and call it via bind() method like this:

```
<button onClick={this.setState.bind(this, {carName:'Honda'})}></button>
```

but I get an error.

> react-dom.development.js:13825 Uncaught Error: Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Object]

Comment: @Jai, react-dom.development.js:13825 Uncaught Error: Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

try using arrow function instead:

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.setState({carName : 'Honda'})}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

dont bind and use arrow function

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.setState({ carName:'Honda' })}></button>
```

Playground.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Playground extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('>>>>>  this.state : ', this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.setState({ carName: 'Honda' })}> try </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Playground;
```

Comment: are you sure? without `bind` it would not result in error

Comment: @Jai yes it will work only if O/P is using class component

Comment: @Jai please check Playground.js in my answer it is working for me

Comment: @JayVaghasiya, sorry, is it true that onClick or any other event in React takes ONLY function?

Comment: @MII Yes you don't need binding

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Class component, by calling `setState()` in `onClick()`, you are calling setState in `render()` which is against React principles. You should call setState outside the render function.

The ideal approach is to call a `handleClick` function like below;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

state = {
 carName: null
}

handleClick = data => {
  this.setState({ carName: data.carName })
}

class Sample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.handleClick({ carName: 'Honda' })}> try </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sample;
```

Secondly, you should not have `.bind(this)` in `setState`